# Updating a ref in a change Firebase trigger in Google Cloud Functions

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I have a `messages` entry that looks like this:

```
firbaseapp
 messages
   -KiG85eYMH7jfKph4bl3
      created: 1492788734743
      title: "title"
      message: "message"
```

I want to send a notification when new entries are added to this list so 
I added this cloud function:

```
exports.sendMessageNotification = functions.database.ref('/messages/').onWrite(event => {

    event.data.forEach(message => {

        if (message.val().notificationSent) {
            return;
        }

        admin.messaging().sendToTopic(...)
        .then(res => {
            return db.ref('/messages').child(message.key).update({
                notificationSent: (new Date()).getTime(),
            });
        })
    });
});
```

Problem is `message.key` is `messages-KiG85eYMH7jfKph4bl3` so when I try to save it, it creates a new entry instead of updating the existing one:

```
firbaseapp
 messages
   -KiG85eYMH7jfKph4bl3
      created: 1492788734743
      title: "title"
      message: "message"
   -messages-KiG85eYMH7jfKph4bl3
      notificationSent: 123434554534
```

What I wanted is for `notificationSent` to be set on the existing entry.

I also tried using `message.ref` but I get the same result.

**So what is the best way to update a list item in firebase in a cloud function?**

Comment: Any reason why you can't simply trigger on `/messages/{messageId}`? So `functions.database.ref('/messages/{messageId}')`.

Comment: The message id is generated by firebase when I call `push()` so the question is - how can I get the message id from the change?

Comment: `const messageId = event.params.messageId`

Comment: Getting ref path wildcards is [expained here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/functions.database#.ref)

Comment: I just got both of your answers. If I listen on `/messages/{messageId}` is there any way i can get the ref from the event or do I need to build it with `db.ref('/messages').child(event.params.messageId);`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this accomplishes what you want to do and also answers your questions in the comments:

```
exports.sendMessageNotification = functions.database.ref('/messages/{messageId}')
  .onWrite(event => {
    const messageId = event.params.messageId;
    console.log('messageId=', messageId);

    if (event.data.current.child('notificationSent').val()) {
        console.log('already sent');
        return;
    }

    const ref = event.data.ref; // OR event.data.adminRef

    admin.messaging().sendToTopic(...)
        .then(res => {
            return ref.update({
                // Caution: this update will cause onWrite() to fire again
                notificationSent: (new Date()).getTime(),
            });
        })
});
```